# Deploying a Pre Compiled Web Site Project

Tags: asp.net, deployment, vs-web-site-project

So I have a website project, which I precompile when I publish.

I have a question, when I need to make a small change to the deployed site, do I have to rebuild, re-publish and deploy the entire website structure again, or can I just copy the modified aspx page and the bin directory?

Please let me know!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145803/complete-deploy-vs-out-of-cycle-deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is going to depend on how you did the precompiling of the site.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx), if you did a precompile for deployment, the process takes aspx files and processes any internal code in them, so you will need to recompile everything.

If you did a precompile for deployment and update, the aspx files are not taken into consideration, so provided all you did was some UI changes, you can push the updated aspx file up without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to republish locally and then copy up the modified published pages and the bin folder.

You shouldn't need to upload everything.

Comment: I'll give it a try on my devserver

Answer (score 1):

If you pre-compile epending on the options you have chosen you may be able to edit the .aspx page i.e. HTML code, but not the code-behind..

If the .aspx pages become just placeholders i.e. they are empty inside except for a single comment, you cant.